# How to absolute cell referencing in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

In excel absolute cell reference means you can refer to any desired cell. For example, to refer to cell A1, one can use $a$1. Is there any equivalent way to do the same in gnuplot? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no generic way to access an arbitrary cell during plotting. When plotting, only all columns of the current row are available.

If you need only very few values, you can use the `stats` command to extract the respective values. But this becomes very unhandy for more values:

```
col = 1
row = 1
stats 'file.txt' every ::(row-1)::(row-1) using col nooutput
val = STATS_min
print sprintf('cell (%d,%d) = %f', col, row, val)
```

With the file

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

This prints:

> cell (1,1) = 1.000000

For plotting, use e.g.

```
plot 'file.txt' using ($1-val):2
```

which uses the first column relative to the value in the first row ($A$1) for the x-axis.

Comment: Many thanks! Now what if I want to do math operation like A1-$A$1, is there any workaround?

Comment: Don't fully know what you mean. But if you have e.g. `col=1; row=2; ...` and so `val` contains the values of the first col in the first row, you can do `plot 'file.txt' using ($1-val):2` to have on the x-axis the value relative to the first row. See my edit.